# Which is the best way to monitor multiple windows service - Timer or Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I have a project which monitors multiple windows services in the system. What this project does is it monitors all those services whether they are working or not. If they have stopped working, then there will be a mail sent to the concern person regarding it.

To manage all this, There are multiple timers for multiple services. Something like -

```
System.Timers.Timer ServiceOneTimer;
System.Timers.Timer ServiceTwoTimer;
```

Having timer with a specific interval, On their Elapsed event the status of that particular service is checked -

```
private void ServiceOneTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ServiceOneTimer.Stop();
    bool isRunning = CheckServiceOne();

    if (!isRunning)
        SendMail("Sevice 1 has been stopped");
}
```

I was wondering if there is any better way to achieve this? As there may be many services in future which needs to be monitors. Is using timer in that case is advisable? or something else like `Thread` should be used?

Comment: Why do you want to check if Services are running or not at different intervals?Why not keep only one timer, and on Tick check for all services?

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava That's because few services needs to be checked at short interval. Few needs longer interval. I can say every service have its own interval. Can't keep them all same.

Comment: I think you should use Observer design pattern over Timer or Thread.

Comment: Okay - Red Wei already posted what my thoughts were before asking that question. So basically you keep 1 Timer/Thread with minutest possible tick (say 1 second). Next, make a list of all Services to be monitored (wrapping method to test service up or not, Scan Interval into object). Regitser/Subscribe these objects with the Timer/Thread. With every Tick you got to scan the List and check which service needs to be diagnosed. And decrementing the wait time for others.

Comment: Something that I've seen work well is to have a Timer in each the monitored services that will send out a "heartbeat" which not only indicates it's status but, can include things such as alerts, cpu/mem usage, statistics, etc...  The heartbeat can be done by publishing a message and/or persisting it.  Then the monitoring is done by subscribing and/or checking the persisted heartbeat store.

Comment: @RedWei I have seen some answer by you but unable to see it anymore. I was yet to try that.

Comment: @C.Mitchell I have heard first time about "heartbeat", let me check it out.

Comment: @ArpitGupta I simply just desmonstrate the Observe pattern but have a little different with Prateek's implement. Basically, I send a notificattion inside the service class to the handler class (send email class for example). You can send to many handler classes not only one. The pro of this way is you don't need a Thread or a Timer at all and you can add more handler classes but the downside is it only works when you can modify the service's code. But I think it won't work in this case because the user can force a service to end unexpectedly.

Comment: So best way to solve this problem is have a 3rd service that checks all others services is running or not. Still use the Observer pattern.

Comment: Unless you have a few hundred/thousands of services to monitor, which seems unlikely, there's really nothing wrong about using a timer per service